# Springboot Logging Pattern For Rolling Logs

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I am using Springboot version 2.7 and trying to configure the log pattern to be daily rolling.

I am currently using just the application properties file to configure the logging as that's the preference.

I added the following line in the properties file but does not seem to work

`logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=myservice-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`

Any clues what I may be missing?

Also, is there a way to check daily log rolling without having to wait for EOD :)

Comment: *but does not seem to work*  is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to specify the file name:

```
logging.file.name=myservice.log
```

then you can use the rolling file name pattern

```
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=myservice-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
```

To force the file change you could set the size to something small

```
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=100K
```

To specify the directory you must set this property

```
logging.file.path=/var/logs
```

The documentation can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging

Comment: If I use the above, the file names and rolling works fine, but the logs are then saved in some unexpected directory. I am trying to save the logs in a specific dir say /dev/logs

I tried prefixing 1st and 2nd property with the path, but then the rolling policy stops working altogether. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think logging.file.name OR logging.file.path property works, but both don't work in conjunction by the looks of it. If I prefix the file path for my property 1 and 2, I get everything working fine on local, but on my prod environment the rolling policy does not.

Comment: 2 small changes required for spring boot 3.2: %i and KB: logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern=myservice.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=100KB